Two families of isomorphic structures have isomorphic ultraproduct.
I am trying to prove the following result:

Let $(\underline{M}_i)_{i\in I}$, $(\underline{N}_i)_{i\in I}$ be two families of structures such that, for all $i\in I$, $\underline{M}_i \cong \underline{N}_i$. In such situation it holds that $\prod_{i\in I} \underline{M}_i /U\cong \prod_{i\in I} \underline{N}_i /U$ where $U$ is an ultrafilter on $I$ and $\prod_{i\in I} \underline{M}_i /U$ denotes the ultraproduct of the family $(\underline{M}_i)_{i\in I}$.

What I tried was to define:
\begin{equation}
h:\prod\underline{M}_i \to \prod\underline{N}_i
\end{equation}
such that $h(m_1,\dots,m_n,\dots)=(h_1(m_1),\dots,h_n(m_n),\dots)$ where $h_i$ is the isomorphism between $\underline{M}_i$ and $\underline{N}_i$. Now I think I managed to prove that $h$ is an isomorphism between $\prod\underline{M}_i$ and $\prod\underline{N}_i$, however I can't see if such an application descend to the quotient, thus giving me the required isomorphism. Now, $h$ descend to the quotient if given two $m,\overline{m}\in \prod\underline{M}_i$, where $m=(m_1,\dots,m_n\dots)$ and $\overline{m}=(\overline{m}_1,\dots,\overline{m}_n,\dots)$, the fact that $\{i\in I: m_i=\overline{m}_i\}\in U$ implies that $\{i\in I: h_i(m_i)=h_i(\overline{m}_i)\}\in U$.
So first of all, am I on the right path to prove the result? Am I wrong in any part of my attempt? How do I conclude the proof from this?
Any help is very much appreciated :)

It descends to the quotient in exactly the way as is required using the properties of the ultrafilter.  You are on the right path - the proof is very direct (almost trivial).  For some guiding intuition, see: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/06/25/ultrafilters-nonstandard-analysis-and-epsilon-management/

Oh... I think I got it and it really is trivial. $m_i=\overline{m}_i$ obviously implies $h_i(m_i)=h_i(\overline{m}_i)$, hence ${i\in I : m_i=\overline{m}_i}\subseteq {i\in I : h_i(m_i)=h_i(\overline{m}_i)}$ since ultrafilters are closed over supersets, ${i\in I : m_i=\overline{m}_i}\in U \implies {i\in I : h_i(m_i)=h_i(\overline{m}_i)}\in U$. I don't know how I couldn't see it

@WiggedFern936 In fact, since each $h_i$ is injective, ${i\in I:m_i = \overline{m}_i} = {i\in I:h(m_i) = h(\overline{m}_i)}$. Let me give you a more "philosophical" explanation: a structural construction like the ultraproduct couldn't possibly produce non-isomorphic outputs from isomorphic inputs. Isomorphic structures only differ by the identity of the elements of their underlying sets, so unless a construction "looks at" the nature of the elements, it is blind to the difference between isomorphic structures.

Or, to use Tao's "voting" analogy, you'd have to somehow bias the vote to get something else - but the "voting rules" of the ultraproduct are picked specifically so that it can't happen.
